# How to refresh SQL Server database from an ASP Web application?

Tags: sql, asp.net, imacros

I have an ASP.NET web app that launches a few iMacros scripts. 
Each script extracts data from a different website and writes that data into an SQL Server database.

When the imacros scripts finish their task, the web app goes into a function that should retrieve all the information the scripts have written in the database.

The problem is the database is not refreshed and the SqlDataReader doesn't have any rows. I need to manually open SSMS and right click on the database and refresh it. Only then I can see the data.

Is there a way to do this in code ? like an SqlCommand or T-SQL(stored proc)??
I tried to find more information online but I couldn't really find an example that applies to my situation. I only found something about BindingSource and SqlDataAdapter but I don't think it's what I need here.

I need to refresh the database after all the imacros scripts have finished extracting and the final data should be retrieved with an SqlCommand like Select * From table (I use * because I don't know exactly how many columns I'm going to have in the end), and it should be added to a DataGrid for display.

Any tips ? Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the data writes in a transaction? I don't know much about I macros, but it sounds like the data isn't being committed by the I macro scripts.

Comment: Imacros has nothing to do with this. I put all the extracted data into a datatable and I use SqlBulkCopy to copy that datatable into sql server. This part is ok, the data is extracted successfully. I just need to refresh the database first, to be able to do a select * from [the table where I wrote the data coming from each imacros script]. The basic idea is that I'm running these imacros scripts in parallel and at the end I want to gather all the data they extracted. You might be right with the commit part. Can I issue a commit from an SqlCommand ? Would that help update the database ?

Comment: You don't need to right click the database and refresh it. That just tells SSMS to requery the database. If you've inserted the data and you're not using a transaction, then it's already there. If you are using a transaction, you just need to commit it.

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes the data is already there, but I'm not commiting it. I'm using SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock. Should I put this to UseInternalTransaction, since I have multiple threads that will be commiting at the same time ? I don't really know how to do the commit with a bulkcopy.

Comment: You can see how to handle transactions in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx).